# SQL Server - How to round up or down decimals?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, rounding

I would like to be abble to round up or down 10.823. Expected result:

```
rounding down = 10.82
rounding up = 10.83
```

Knowing that `round(10.823, 2)` only rounds down. How to round it up?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are correct, `round` is the wrong tool for this job. Instead, you should use [`floor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178531.aspx) and [`ceiling`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189818.aspx). Unfortunately, they do not have a precision parameter like `round`, so you'd have to simulate it using division and multiplication:

```
SELECT FLOOR(value * 100) / 100 AS rounded_down,
       CEILING(value * 100) / 100 AS rounded_up
FROM   mytable
```

Comment: Thank you. Working like a charm eventhough I hoped MS would have come with something more integrated...