# How to use bigquery round up results to 4 digits after decimal point?

Tags: google-bigquery

We don't have decimal data type in BigQuery now. So I have to use float

But

In Bigquery float division

0.029*50/100=0.014500000000000002

Although

0.021*50/100=0.0105

To round the value up

I have to use round(floatvalue*10000)/10000.

Is this the right way to deal with decimal data type now in BigQuery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that this question deserves a different answer now.

The premise of the question is "We don't have decimal data type in BigQuery now."

But now we do: You can use `NUMERIC`:

```sql
SELECT CAST('0.029' AS NUMERIC)*50/100

# 0.0145
```

Just make your column  is `NUMERIC` instead of `FLOAT64`, and you'll get the desired results.

Answer (score 16):

Depends on your coding preferences - for example you can just use simple `ROUND(floatvalue, 4)`
Depends on how exactly you need to round - up or down - you can respectively adjust expression
For example `ROUND(floatvalue + 0.00005, 4)`

See all rounding functions for BigQuery Standard SQL at below link

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#rounding-functions

Comment: Check the new answer for precise results with `NUMERIC` https://stackoverflow.com/a/62315854/132438

Comment: Note that the logic of ROUND(floatvalue + 0.00005, 4) will also round up figures that shouldn't be rounded up. Example: mathematically, rounding up to the 4th decimal place, 1.0000 should result in 1.0000. However, with this logic, it will result in 1.0001.

Answer (score 1):

Rounding up in most SQL dialects is not a built-in function unless you're fortunate enough to be rounding up to an integer. In this case, [CEIL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/mathematical_functions#ceil) is a quick and reliable solution.

In the case of rounding decimals up, we can also leverage CEIL, albeit with a couple of additional steps.

The procedure:

1. Multiply your value to move the last decimal to the tenths position. Ex. 18.234 becomes 1823.4 by multiplying by 100. (*n* * 100)
2. Use CEIL() to round up to the nearest integer. In our example, CEIL(*n*) = 1824.
3. Divide this result by the same figure used in step 1. In our example, *n* / 100 = 18.24.

Simplifying these steps leaves us with the below logic:

```
SELECT CEIL(value * 100) / 100 as rounded_up;
```

The same logic can be used to round down using the [FLOOR](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/mathematical_functions#floor) function as such:

```
FLOOR(value * 100) / 100 AS rounded_down;
```

---

Thanks to @Mureinik for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30290307/3907405).