# Float precision in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

Bigquery has a float datatype for decimal values. However float does not allow me to set the precision. When I load from a flat file the precision of source is not maintained.

for e.g if I have a value 1.6667 in my flat file, once I load it to BigQuery the table show 1.66666689762

we can build a view to show the value with the desired precision, however the requirement is to have the value in the table with a specific precision

Is there  way to do that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use bigquery round up results to 4 digits after decimal point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43006002/how-to-use-bigquery-round-up-results-to-4-digits-after-decimal-point)

Comment: I think this question needs a different answer: Don't use FLOAT64, use `NUMERIC` - since you want "have the value in the table with a specific precision"